# Unable to invite teachers, students to Classroom via API

Tags: google-api, google-classroom

Having an issue with google classroom api

Using Google Classroom API v1, authorized with oAuth2, requesting

```
teachers.create({
 courseId,
 requestBody: {
  userId: email
 }
})
```

and getting the following error:

```
config: {
>      url: 'https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/237584048292/teachers',
>      method: 'POST',
>      data: {
>        courseId: '237584048292',
>        profile: {},
>        userId: 'dgrz5.0@gmail.com'
>      },
>      body: '{"courseId":"237584048292","profile":{},"userId":"dgrz5.0@gmail.com"}',
>    },
>    data: {
>      error: {
>        code: 403,
>        message: 'The caller does not have permission',
>        errors: [Array],
>        status: 'PERMISSION_DENIED'
>      }
>    },
>    
>    status: 403,
>    statusText: 'Forbidden',
>    request: {
>      responseURL: 'https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/237584048292/teachers'
>    }
>  }
```

Comment: Where are you requesting it from? Are you using a particular library? Do you have the right scopes set up? Is the calling account an admin? I would suggest perhaps using the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.teachers/create) to test out your request and make sure its strictly a permission error. If you are using a library, I would suggest going through one of the [quickstart guides](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/get-started) to make sure you have a properly authenticated app (if your request does work in the explorer).

Answer (score 0):

Go to your **storage** section of your Database.Then in **Rules** ,allow read, write and remove the condition for authentication.

Comment: How is this useful in terms of api ? Database has nothing to do with google api calls.